# Junit 5 csv file as input for one test method

Tags: java, junit5

So I found that junit 5 has annotation

```
@ParametrizedTest
@CsvFileSource(filenames)
Void testmethod(String column1, String column2)
```

So every line of this csv will be as separated test case.
In my case I need to create one big test from all data from csv.

Junit provide smth like ArgumentAggregator it can help out with creating object from csv columns to

```
@ParametrizedTest
@CsvFileSource(filenames)
Void testMethod(@AggregateWith(PersonAggregator.class) Person person)
```

So final question is how to squash all csv lines to one test like

```
@ParametrizedTest
@CsvFileSource(filenames)
Void testMethod(@AggregateWith(PersonAggregator.class) List<Person> person)
```

I can manually read csv file and squash all lines in aggregator, but i believe there should be some built in solution ?

Comment: My suggestion is you use one of the many CSV file reader libraries to read in the data. Jupiter´s CSVFileSource is not made for that purpose but explicitly intended to support parameterized testing.

Comment: If I understand the goal then you are no longer using a parameterized test. Unless you're intending to run the test with multiple times with different `List` argument?

Comment: So it can be without parametrized or it can be parametrized but one test per csv file. No test per line in csv

Comment: Ye I did it using aggregatedWith annotation. But i was sure that it should be built in somewhere :(

Comment: Can you show your `PersonAggregator` class?

Comment: @slaw example here https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5 and use @ ValueSource to pass filenames to aggregator